# WYSIWYG editor not appearing in CiviCRM and Drupal

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg

I am trying to edit a "Message Template" in CiviCRM 4.7.30 and Drupal 7.57, but the "HTML Format" is not showing a WYSIWYG editor, just a plain text editor.

I have gone to CiviCRM -> Administer -> Customise Data and Screens -> Display Preferences.  The "WYSIWYG Editor" setting is "CKEditor" (this is the only option).

In Drupal, I have the WYSIWYG module installed.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Carl

Comment: Can you run a comparison with what is on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: It is the same - the "HTML Format" section shows the raw HTML of the template, rather than a WYSIWYG".

Comment: Ah, I've figured out the problem after looking at the code in ./sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/MessageTemplates.php.  The WYSIWYG editor is only shown if the message template is not a system message

Comment: Ah right. That wasn't obvious in the question. Anyhow, go ahead and Answer and Accept your own question and help close this off

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I've figured out the problem after looking at the code in ./sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/MessageTemplates.php. The WYSIWYG editor is only shown if the message template is not a system message

Comment: Yes, system message templates use Smarty which I guess is why WYSIWYG isn't offered